# SAS print text from file to spreadsheet

Tags: sas, sas-ods

Is there a way to print the contents of a .txt file to a tab using ods tagsets.excelxp? I have a script that creates a .xml file with several tabs, and on one of the tabs I'd like to print the lines of the code itself, so that I can send the .xml file to someone and they can have the code that I used to produce the output.  I have the code saved separately as a .txt.  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way would be to read the text file lines into a Data Set.  Then use PROC PRINT to print to your output destination;

```
data lines;
infile "path/to/file.txt";
format code $2000.;
input;
code = _infile_;
run;

proc print data=lines noobs;
run;
```

Comment: Happy to help.  If this answers your question, please accept the answer and up-vote.